# Ionic Framework : @ionic/angular 5.3.2

Tags: ionic-framework

We have a requirement of creating a container app using an ionic framework for android and iOS. On launching this container app, it should directly show a responsive webpage inside the native wrapper(review).I have used the below command for creating the ionic project.

```
sudo ionic start newApp blank --type angular
```

Now I am confused about below version details.

**Ionic:**

```
   Ionic CLI                     : 6.11.7 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.3.2
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1000.8
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.0.8
   @angular/cli                  : 10.0.8
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3
```

**Utility:**

```
   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : not installed
```

**System:**

```
   NodeJS : v12.18.3 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.14.6
   OS     : macOS Catalina
```

My Doubts:

- ionic/angular 5.3.2, does that mean ionic version is 5.3.2 or is that angular version.
- Also is that angularJS or Angular 8/7/9/etc.

Comment: 5.3.2 is ionic version

Answer (score 1):

To Answer your doubts :

1. The 5.3.2 version is the Ionic Version
2. It is angular 10 you are using

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with ionic info you can find in the ****Ionic Framework** field** indicates the version that the project is using, in your case is 5.3.2 version

To get the version of angular you can go into **node_modules/@angular/core/package.json** and check **version field**

Or you should install the angular client and run ng --version which will indicate which version of angular you are using in the project in **field Angular**